# Integral $\int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}} \sqrt{\cosh^2\bigg(\frac{x}{a}\bigg) +1} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

While doing an arc length problem I found the following integral:

$$Length = \int_{T_{1}}^{T_{2}} \sqrt{\cosh^2\bigg(\frac{x}{a}\bigg) +1} dx$$

I tried using $\cosh x = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$ but I got nowhere. Also, I don't know if there's any useful identity like $\cosh^2 x - \sinh^2 x = 1$ that could be useful. Thanks.

EDIT:

Here's the original problem:

> Find the arc length of a function defined by $\gamma = (x, a \sinh(\frac{x}{a}))$ in the interval $[T_1, T_2]$.

Comment: Wolframalpha suggests this integral is not expressible with standard functions. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sqrt%28cosh%5E2%28x%2Fa%29+%2B1%29+dx
Keep in mind not all integrable functions have antiderivatives that can be expressed as combinations of known functions. Maybe you made a mistake earlier in the problem?

Comment: Starting from the arc length of the ellipse, a lot of arc lengths cannot have elementary solution.

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando Thanks for your comment, I made an edit with the original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $\sinh^2(\frac{x}{a}) +2 = \cosh^2(\frac{x}{a}) + 1$ which directly follows from the identity you mentioned
$$=\int_{T_1}^{T_2} \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\frac{\sinh^2(\frac{x}{a})}{2} + 1}$$
Let $u = \frac{xi}{a}$ and $dx = -ia\text{ }du$ and use $\sinh(z) = -i\sin(iz)$
$$ = -\sqrt{2}ia\int_{T_1}^{T_2} \sqrt{1 - \frac{\sin^2(u)}{2}}du$$
The integral is the incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind $E(u \vert \frac{1}{2})$. Undoing the substitution and using this we get
$$-\sqrt{2}ia E\Big(\frac{xi}{a} \Big\vert \frac{1}{2}\Big) \Bigg\vert_{T_1}^{T_2}$$
[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind) is an article on the incomplete elliptic integrals

Comment: You have to change the limits of integration also.